# jackson timestamp mapping bug?

Tags: java, json, timestamp, jackson

I get the data from the mobile client as the json file.

But, if only the time stamp, it can not normally receive data. 
In the end, truncated 3-digit number.

So the date is completely wrong.

This is my source.

json file

```
{
  "startPhotoAddress": "Great Ocean Road, Hordern Vale",
  "createTimeStamp": "1356998400",
  "startPhotoTimeStamp": "1356998430"
}
```

In the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/moment", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody JsonNode setMomentJson(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Moment moment){
```

In the model

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Moment{
    private Timestamp createTimeStamp;

    public Timestamp getCreateTimeStamp() {
        return createTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setCreateTimeStamp(Timestamp createTimeStamp) {
        this.createTimeStamp = createTimeStamp;
    }
}
```

I get  **createTimeStamp : 1970-01-17 01:56:38.4**

it use only 1356998 from 1356998400 of createTimeStamp.

If it receive a string, not a problem.

Please, what is the problem?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are receiving timestamp values in seconds, not milliseconds, you can make a setter to accept a long type and multiply the input value on 1000, and create a Timestamp instance by calling a constructor. Something like this:

```
public class Moment{
    private Timestamp createTimeStamp;

    public Timestamp getCreateTimeStamp() {
        return createTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setCreateTimeStamp(long createTimeStamp) {
        this.createTimeStamp = new Timestamp(createTimeStamp * 1000);
    }
}
```